# Coercive problems

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, bounded-variation

this is the complete problem

[image]

[image]

[image]

and i have a problem that is :
i dont understand step 2:
step 1:"shows that $m>-\infty$ i dont understand how to prove it ?

can someone help me please ?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $a=\|u\|\geq0$. Then by using $2Ca\leq a^2+C^2$, we have
$$
I(u) \geq \frac {a^2}2 - Ca \geq \frac {a^2}2 - \frac12(a^2+C^2) = -\frac12 C^2,
$$
fort any $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$. So the infimum of $I(u)$ as $u$ varies in $H^1_0(\Omega)$ must be larger than $-C^2/2$.

Comment: Thank you, please do you know why :there exist $w\in l^2(\Omega)~~\text{such that}~~|u_k(x)|\leq w(x) $ a.e in $\Omega$ and for all $k$ ? please thank you

Comment: @Vrouvrou: What is $l^2(\Omega)$?

Comment: a hilbert space !

Comment: the function $u$ such that $\int_{\Omega}|u(x)|^2 dx <\infty$

Comment: Maybe you want to post that as a new question? I would have appreciated if you voted up my answer and then asked additional questions.